# How to know what file was saved when using asynchronous filesystem fileWrite()?

Tags: node.js

I have the following code and I want to know what file was saved:

```
import fs from "fs";

class MyClass {

    saveFiles() {
    
       // loop through 1000000 files 
       for loop {
           fs.writeFile(uploadFilePath, file.buffer, this.fileSaveHandler);
       }
    }
    
    
    fileSaveHandler(error: any = null) {
        // what file was just saved? 
        // i need to do other stuff here
    }
}
```

It looks like it's impossible to do it this way in node js.

I do NOT want to use promises or inline call backs.

Comment: Read the directory and see what you got?

Comment: *I do NOT want to use promises or inline call backs* - why not?